# showInstalledExtensions not found

Tags: visual-studio-code

So I'm using VS code in my Windows machine and I've customized my keybindings and have this shortcut.

Show/Hide installed extensions

```
keybindings.json
{
    "key": "ctrl+k ctrl+x",
    "command": "workbench.extensions.action.showInstalledExtensions"
},
```

It's working fine before until now that I pressed the shortcut `ctrl+k ctrl+x`, it's not working anymore and I'm getting the error below.

`'workbench.extensions.action.showInstalledExtensions' not found`

I tried removing and re-adding that specific binding to see if it will work, but still the error persists.

Answer (score 2):

Did you check the **Default Keybindings**?

This is the default from what I see on mine.

```
{ "key": "ctrl+shift+x",          "command": "workbench.view.extensions",
                                  "when": "viewContainer.workbench.view.extensions.enabled" },
```

So in your case you can update it as follows

```
{
    "key": "ctrl+k ctrl+x",
    "command": "workbench.view.extensions",
    "when": "viewContainer.workbench.view.extensions.enabled"
},
```